# Sequence of Subsets of Real numbers converge implies their infimums also converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence

Let sequence of subsets of Real numbers $A_n$, $n\geq 1$ converge to $A$. Does the sequence of Inf $A_n$ converge to Inf$A$?
The sequence need not be monotonic.

Comment: If the sequence is not monotonic, then what does it mean for it to "converge" to $A$?

Comment: More generally, what does it mean for a sequence of subsets of reals to converge.

Comment: A sequence of sets $A_n$ converge to a set $A$ means that its indicator function converge pointwise. You can check this that for monotonic sets, it happens to be instersection/unions.

Answer (score 2):

No -- consider for example
$$ A_n = (0,\tfrac1n) \cup \{1\} $$
This converges to $\{1\}$, but each $A_n$ has infimum $0$.

Comment: I think it converges to $\{1\}$ in the sense of pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions, but to $\{0,1\}$ with respect to the Hausdorff distance? Might be nice to get some clarification from the OP as to what sort of "convergence" he means.